# iOS, AFNetworking - "Clear" NSSTring with JSON response

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking to get JSON from the server, but response contains a little bit more then just JSON, so I cannot parse it:

```
 array(11) {
   ["something"]=>
   string(4) "none"
   (...)
  }
  [[],{"JSONDataNow":
      (...)
  }]
```

Is this possible to remove other data then JSON from string?

Comment: If you can imagine it, you can code it. Yes, possible.

Answer (score 2):

The server is not returning JSON. It's returning a JSON-like string. Either fix the server to return JSON or write your own custom parser based on the custom rules used by the server.

Attempting to write a pre-processor that turns non-JSON string into JSON is not a good idea. You will have all the difficulties of writing a custom parser with none of the benefits of being the master of your own syntax.